# Memory usage accumulated in while loop

Tags: python, memory, pandas

My code includes this `while` loop:

```
while A.shape[0] > 0:
    idx = A.score.values.argmax()
    one_center = A.coordinate.iloc[idx]
    # peak_centers and peak_scores are python lists
    peak_centers.append(one_center)
    peak_scores.append(A.score.iloc[idx])
    # exclude the coordinates around the selected peak
    A = A.loc[(A.coordinate <= one_center - exclusion) | (A.coordinate >= one_center + exclusion)]
```

`A` is a pandas `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
   score  coordinate
0  0.158           1
1  0.167           2
2  0.175           3
3  0.183           4
4  0.190           5
```

I am trying to find the maximum score (a peak) in `A`, then exclude some coordinates (a couple hundred in this case) around the previously found peak, then find the next peak and so on.

`A` here is a very large pandas `DataFrame`. Before running this `while` loop, the ipython session used 20% of machine memory. I thought that running this `while` loop would only cause memory consumption to drop because I am excluding some data from the `DataFrame`. However, what I observe is that memory usage keeps increasing and at some point machine memory is exhausted.

Is there anything I missed here? Do I need to explicitly free memory somewhere?

Here is a short script that can replicate the behavior using random data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame({'score':np.random.random(132346018), 'coordinate':np.arange(1, 132346019)})
peak_centers = []
peak_scores = []
exclusion = 147
while A.shape[0] > 0:
    idx = A.score.values.argmax()
    one_center = A.coordinate.iloc[idx]
    # peak_centers and peak_scores are python lists
    peak_centers.append(one_center)
    peak_scores.append(A.score.iloc[idx])
    # exclude the coordinates around the selected peak
    A = A.loc[(A.coordinate <= one_center - exclusion) | (A.coordinate >= one_center + exclusion)]

# terminated the loop after memory consumption gets to 90% of machine memory
# but peak_centers and peak_scores are still short lists
print len(peak_centers)
# output is 16
```

Comment: Do you print the length of the list? Perhaps you've missed something and it's getting large despite your assumption!?

Comment: My first guess is that A.shape[0] never hits 0. While loops are a good way to accidentally create an infinite loop, and you are adding to peak_centers and peak_scores on every loop. If you messed this up, they will keep getting larger until they run out of space. It is highly recommended that if you must use a while loop, to review it very carefully and ensure that the while test gets closer to being False on every loop.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason so far. See the updated code to replicate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DataFrame` is simply too big to deal with. The memory load doubles while you're executing this line:

```
A = A.loc[(A.coordinate <= one_center - exclusion) | (A.coordinate >= one_center + exclusion)]
```

That's because you're assigning a new value to `A`, so memory is allocated for a new `DataFrame` while the old one is being filtered. The new one is almost the same size as the old one because you're selecting almost all of the data points. That eats up enough memory for two copies of `A`, and that's without taking account of extra memory for the bookkeeping that the `loc` implementation does.

Apparently `loc` causes pandas to allocate enough memory for an additional copy of the data. I'm not sure why this is. I presume it's a performance optimization of some sort. This means that you end up consuming, at peak memory usage, four times the size of the `DataFrame`. Once `loc` is done and the unallocated memory is freed—which you can force by calling `gc.collect()`—the memory load drops down to double the size of the `DataFrame`. On the next call to `loc`, everything is doubled and you're back up to a quadruple load. Garbage-collect again, and you're back down to double. This will continue as long as you like.

To verify what's going on, run this modified version of your code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import gc

A = pd.DataFrame({'score':np.random.random(32346018), 'coordinate':np.arange(1, 32346019)})
peak_centers = []
peak_scores = []
exclusion = 147
count = 0
while A.shape[0] > 0:
    gc.collect()  # Force garbage collection.
    count += 1    # Increment the iteration count.
    print('iteration %d, shape %s' % (count, A.shape))
    raw_input()   # Wait for the user to press Enter.
    idx = A.score.values.argmax()
    one_center = A.coordinate.iloc[idx]
    # peak_centers and peak_scores are python lists
    peak_centers.append(one_center)
    peak_scores.append(A.score.iloc[idx])
    print(len(peak_centers), len(peak_scores))
    # exclude the coordinates around the selected peak
    A = A.loc[(A.coordinate <= one_center - exclusion) | (A.coordinate >= one_center + exclusion)]
```

Press the Enter key between iterations and keep an eye on memory usage with `top` or a similar tool.

At the start of the first iteration, you'll see a memory usage of `x` percent. On the second iteration, after `loc` was called for the first time, memory usage doubles to `2x`. Subsequently, you'll see it go up to `4x` during each call to `loc`, then go down to `2x` after garbage collection.

Comment: I kinda figured what was going on after running the code. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @qkhhly Check out my answer as well. I can confirm by using this same gadget with `top` that if you use `drop` with `inplace=True` the memory is not doubling from copies on each pass. Inplace dropping seems more like idiomatic pandas to me than making a copy only to instantly garbage collect the now-defunct original.

Answer (score 3):

Use `DataFrame.drop` with `inplace=True` if you want to destructively mutate `A` without copying a large subset of `A`'s data.

```
places_to_drop = ~(A.coordinate - one_center).between(-exclusion, exclusion)
A.drop(A.index[np.where(places_to_drop)], inplace=True)
```

[The place where the original usage of `loc` ultimately bottoms out](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L936) is in the `_NDFrameIndexer` method `_getitem_iterable`. `_LocIndexer` is a child class of `_NDFrameIndexer` and an instance of `_LocIndexer` gets created and populates the `loc` property of a `DataFrame`.

In particular, `_getitem_iterable` performs a check for a Boolean index, which occurs in your case. Then a new array of the Boolean locations is created (which is wasteful of memory when `key` is already in Boolean format).

```
inds, = key.nonzero()
```

and then finally the "true" locations are returned within a copy:

```
return self.obj.take(inds, axis=axis, convert=False)
```

From the code: `key` will be your Boolean index (i.e. the result of the expression `(A.coordinate <= one_center - exclusion) | (A.coordinate >= one_center + exclusion)`) and `self.obj` will be the parent `DataFrame` instance from which `loc` was invoked, so `obj` here is just `A`.

The `DataFrame.take` documentation explains that the default behavior is to make a copy. In the current implementation of the indexers, there is no mechanism allowing you to pass a keyword argument through that will eventually be used to perform `take` without making a copy.

On any reasonable modern machine, using the `drop` approach should be problem-free for the size of data you describe, so it is not the case that `A`'s size is to blame.

Comment: Thanks for the explaining the internals. It didn't seem to prevent the memory usage from shooting to over 90%, although it didn't shoot up so fast as the previous version. Ultimately, I have decided not to use the approach in this post. It worked reasonably fast for me in smaller sized `A`, but it's too slow for larger `A`.

Comment: @qkhhly I suspect something else is going on then, because when I memory profile this way (with `drop`) using the snippet that Michael Laszlo posted, I do not see memory growth. It is unfortunate the the pandas indexer code is so obtuse and hard to understand, because unexpected problems like this seem to pop up a lot.

Comment: I didn't force garbage collection, that could be the reason.